# what does 'boot off' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading this article: https://qr.ae/TWFMOe

What does '**boot off of our throats**' mean here?

"The larger challenge is building an economy that restores our autonomy, gets the **boot off of our throats** and puts our energies and innovation to work in addressing the real challenges of this era, like climate change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited usage refers to the *metaphoric* image of an oppressor having his boot / heel on the throat / neck of a victim (the hapless victim can't move / breathe). The implication here is that *the current economic system* is responsible for this oppression (so it needs to be "rebuilt").

The reference to ***restoring our autonomy*** (giving us back our independence / freedom) suggests that the writer is part of some socially / economically disadvantaged group seeking the freedom to make their own choices. Specifically, so they can focus on things like combating climate change, rather than social injustice.

---

If the victim (with that metaphoric boot ***on*** his throat) could speak, he might say *Get your boot **off** [**of**] my throat!* As [this NGram for ***Get your hands off (of) me!***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your%20hands%20off%20me%2Cyour%20hands%20off%20of%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyour%20hands%20off%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20hands%20off%20of%20me%3B%2Cc0) shows, the second preposition *(**of**)* isn't *normally* included in such contexts. Arguably the "double preposition" form is slightly more "emphatic", but it doesn't really make much difference - it's just a stylistic choice.

Also, because it's an important part of Anglophones' linguistic heritage, I can't resist flagging up George Orwell's closely related metaphoric usage in ***1984***, where he characterizes his dystopian future as [*a boot stamping on a face forever*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stamping%20on%20a%20face%20forever%22)

Finally, note that native speakers will be divided as to whether the cited usage should feature singular *off of our **throat*** or plural *off of our **throats*** (see [“On their back” or “on their backs”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/on-their-back-or-on-their-backs) as asked on ELU some years ago).

Comment: Even though you can find 'off of', meaning 'from', as far back as Samuel Pepys, many people regard it as very casual, informal, or even illiterate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I expect they'd be the kind of people who supposedly prompted Churchill to say [*This is the type of errant pedantry up with which I will not put*](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/11/14/churchill-on-prepositions/) when told not to end his sentences with prepositions. If there are *still* any such people, I can only hope they keep themselves to themselves.